# Using multi-touch on iPhone & iPad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, multi-touch

How do I get the co-ordinates of 2 touches on an iPhone? (both co-odiantes)??? This is killing me... any sample code would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and its siblings, you will be passed an `NSSet` object containing all the touches. You can get an `NSArray` using `allObjects` method on the set. You can retrieve individual `UITouch` objects using `objectAtIndex:` method. The `UITouch` object can give you coordinates based on any view's frame through the method `locationInView:`. The call will be on the lines of `CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];`.  Do this for all the touches in the array.

If you are using gesture recognizers, the gesture recognizer object has a method `numberOfTouches` that gives you the number of touches and you can retrieve the location of each touch using `locationOfTouch:inView:`.

Comment: Thanks for going into such great detail

Comment: Just out of interest, which one would you do, touches or gestures?

Comment: I think gestures are pretty useful. Unless there is something that they can't be used for, I will use them. Another thing is that they are available only from iOS 3.2 onwards. If you have to support older platforms then go for `touchesBegan:`

Comment: Could you post some source code for gestures? I have given it a try, but to no avail

Comment: There are two things here. First have you set `multipleTouchEnabled` to `NO`. And second, you have to test this on a device.

Comment: sorry, but I'm really confused. Could you possibly post some code for getting it with touchesBegan please?

Comment: Hello @DeepakDanduprolu, can you please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761686/track-touch-points-in-mutlitouch, I need your help

Answer (score 1):

check touches began, touches moved, touches ended, and touches cancelled. here is the link  for this [UIResponder class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)